# Kusto query for iterate string array with filtering

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Now I have data, like
CSVs = `"AAA@XXX.com,BBB@YYY.com,CCC@XXX.com,DDD@ZZZ.com,EEE@YYY.com,FFF@XXX.com"`
apply parse_csv(), then get

```
| data                                                                                       |
| ["AAA@XXX.com", "BBB@YYY.com", "CCC@XXX.com", "DDD@ZZZ.com", "EEE@YYY.com", "FFF@XXX.com"] |
```

How can I simply filter the data to get

```
| XXX.com               | YYY.com        | ZZZ.com  |
|-----------------------|----------------|----------|
| ["AAA", "CCC", "FFF"] | ["BBB", "EEE"] | ["DDD"]  |
```

Key is not how to transform data (AAA@XXX.com -> AAA), but how to split date for each type （XXX.com, YYY.com, ZZZ.com）.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work, though not too efficiently.

Consider adjusting how you consume the data, in terms of output schema, so that you'd be able to remove the last 2 rows:

```
print input = "AAA@XXX.com,BBB@YYY.com,CCC@XXX.com,DDD@ZZZ.com,EEE@YYY.com,FFF@XXX.com"
| mv-apply address = split(input, ",") on (
    parse address with name "@" domain
    | summarize make_list(name) by domain
)
| summarize b = make_bag(pack(domain, list_name))
| evaluate bag_unpack(b)
```

| XXX.com | YYY.com | ZZZ.com |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [ "AAA", "CCC", "FFF" ] | [ "BBB", "EEE" ] | [ "DDD" ] |